# Max. text size of TextView

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

We have ImageView as background and on ImageView some TextViews (something like specific ID card). Everything looks fine until user go to Android settings (not app) and enlarge font size (General, for every application). When he return to application, as text is now bigger, some TextViews do not match the ImageView.
Is it possible to set max. text (font) size for TextView - working on API 24.

Tried with Auto-Sizing but it doesn't work for me as it is for API 26 and more.

```
android:autoSizeText=”uniform” 
autoSizeMaxTextSize=”25sp”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `sp` to `dp` for `TextView` if you are using fixed `ImageView` size.

Never use `sp` inside a fixed sized component. There is a high chance that they might be cut when user enlarges the font in settings. Note that `sp` stands for scale-independent pixel, it means that it will grow depending on user's preferences. However, if you set it as `dp`, it will remain as it is.

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I have some room (free space) if user can't see well and want to enlarge text, so I just wonder if it is possible to set max. size that he can enlarge it. So text is larger but still fits my needs.

Comment: As long as it's sp, no.